# How does this awk command works?

Tags: awk

I have the below data in file and want to separate the lines into two variables - one having the version info and second one with no version info:

```
3f0e86dd5592                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
0cbf659a22db                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
9dd121133805  1.0.48                     1969-12-31T19:00:00
4daa44734d2e  1.0.45,1.0.47,1.0.42       1969-12-31T19:00:00
```

If I run below, I don't get the intended result (which I think, should give me the lines with no version info) .

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "") { print } }' file.txt
```

But  running below, gives me lines with no version:

```
awk '{ if ($3 == "") { print } }' file.txt
```

Why is that?

Comment: Did you try looking up the awk manual? or go through other examples of code that explains this behavior?

Comment: Hint: on the good/bad lines, what are the values of $2 and $3?

Comment: awk '{ print $2}' file.txt
1969-12-31T19:00:00
1969-12-31T19:00:00
1.0.48
1.0.45,1.0.47,1.0.42

Comment: awk '{ print $3}' file1.txt


1969-12-31T19:00:00
1969-12-31T19:00:00

Comment: I think it makes sense now. Correct me if I am wrong, on lines with no version, would have $3 blank. hence getting the intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines have different number of fields. First two lines have 2 fields and the next two have 3 fields each. Use `NF==3` as a condition. `$3==""` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

With fixed-width data, if you're using GNU awk, you can define with size of each field. Then empty fields will consist of only spaces:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "14 27 19"} $2 ~ /^[[:space:]]+$/' file
```

```
3f0e86dd5592                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
0cbf659a22db                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
```

Comment: feel free to correct me I usually believe in your solutions.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question you make it sample with `NF == 2`, If you notice any mistake, please don't hesitate to correct me

```
awk 'NF==2{print}' file
```

or:

```
awk '{if(NF==2) print}' file
```

input :

```
3f0e86dd5592                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
0cbf659a22db                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
9dd121133805  1.0.48                     1969-12-31T19:00:00
4daa44734d2e  1.0.45,1.0.47,1.0.42       1969-12-31T19:00:00
```

output :

```
3f0e86dd5592                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
0cbf659a22db                             1969-12-31T19:00:00
```

Comment: This is correct. It can be as short as `awk 'NF == 2' file` because the default action is to print the line.